# Flutter / Dart - String with UTF8 Hex code to Latin1

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-8

I'm facing a problem here which I haven't been able to find anything on Stackoverflow before or any API to help with it ...
The thing is, I got this String :

`"A_Escadaria--Fernand_L%C3%A9ger.jpg"`

This is the name of a file that I got from the AssetManifest.json

The **%C3%A9** is the UTF8 Hex equivalent to the letter "**é**", which is **latin1** (I guess).

I need to transform those characters to their real equivalent value (which is "é" in this case), but I can't ...
I have used already the `latin1.encode` / `decode`, `utf8.encode` / `decode`, `String.fromCharCodes` .... no results to any combination.

Can someone give me a light on how to resolve this and get a String with the UTF8 Hex converted to their actual characters??

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Flutter, but the thing you're looking for is called "percent encoding." It's also sometimes called URL encoding. Look for something that handles that. It's UTF-8. This isn't related to Latin-1. You probably want something like https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/decodeComponent.html

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly the answer! I didn't know about the term "percent encoding" ... for me, it was simply a hex of UTF8. But it worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment from [@rob-napier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier), I was using the wrong functions to make the conversion, as the term for those Hex UTF-8 codes is called "percent encoding".

So the correct method would be:

```
String correctString = Uri.decodeComponent(stringWithPercentEncodingChars);
```

More information can be found on the website that [@rob-napier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier) posted:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/decodeComponent.html